# How to reuse cell from an UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I have a `UITableView` where I have cells each with an image. Whenever I select one of the cells I change the current cell's image. But when I scroll and the cell or cells get out of sight the cell gets recreated or some, and the default image appears again. I want the changed image to stay on the cells until the view unloads or disappears.

Here is my delegates for the `UITableView`.

```
//UITableview delegate
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Arecipe.IngredientArr.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if(tableView == IngrediensTableView || tableView == ProcedureTableView)
    {
        print("Cell")

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        let ingredient = self.Arecipe.IngredientArr[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = ingredient.UnitValue + " " + ingredient.UnitName + " " + ingredient.Name
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck")
        cell.selectionStyle = .None

        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")

    if(tableView == IngrediensTableView || tableView == ProcedureTableView)
    {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

        if(cell.imageView?.image == UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck"))
        {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Ingr_Check")
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see here is view recycling. This allows `UITableView` to be fast and use less memory.

You should keep the 'checked' state logic separate from the cells.

Add a property to your class that stores the checked `IndexPath`.

```
var checkedIndexPath:NSIndexPath?
```

Then you save the the selected index in `checkedIndexPath`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let previousChecked = checkedIndexPath
    checkedIndexPath = indexPath    
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([previousChecked, checkedIndexPath], withRowAnimation:.Automatic)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if indexPath == checkedIndexPath {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Ingr_Check")        
    }
    else {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck")  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable cell reuse (and improve memory consumption and performance) change this line:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

To:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
        ?? UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

and to refresh the selection status on cell reuse, change this line:

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Ingr_Uncheck")
```

to this:

```
let selected = (tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows ?? []).contains(indexPath)
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: selected ? "Ingr_Check" : "Ingr_Uncheck")
```

This way you will reuse the cells that go out of sight, and will refresh the image based on the selection status of the cell.

I'd recommend you to subclass `UITableViewCell` and move the 'image selection' logic to the `setSelected` method of the cell. Something like this:

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    imageView?.image = UIImage(named: selected ? "Ingr_Check" : "Ingr_Uncheck")
}
```

This way the view controller code would be much cleaner. You can override `prepareForReuse` method in your cells to reset to default state before being reused. To check which cells are selected, you can use `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` to get the list of selected indexes.

Comment: Hi @redent84 thanks for your reply. I change the let cell to what you suggested, but it didn't work. The image still get set to default for the cells that is out of sight (scroll out).

Comment: The problem is that you are not setting the image on `cellForRow`, but in `didSelectRow`. See my edit to see an easier way to managing cell selection.

Comment: I can't find a func called setSelected @redent84

Comment: This method: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/setSelected:animated:

Comment: Ohh I see, but I can't inheritance from multi classes. I already inheritance from UIViewController.

Comment: No, your view controller shouldn't inherit from `UITableViewCell`, I was talking about replacing the standard `UITableViewCell` with a custom class that manages the selected status by itself. I've updated my answer to delegate this logic to the view controller anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97624/discussion-between-redent84-and-loc-dai-le).